# why RegisterClassEx fails

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am creating a window with the following code

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nCmdShow){
    MSG messages;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    DWORD dwrd;

    InitCommonControls();

    //The Window structure
    wc.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    wc.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); //if I comment it RegisterClassEx(&wc) fails with error: ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszMenuName = 0;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;

    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(230, 225, 208)); //(HBRUSH)(COLOR_3DFACE + 1);

    //Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program
    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc)){
        dwrd = GetLastError();

        printf("Error in Function = WinMain() at line = %d, with error code = %X \n", __LINE__ - 3, (unsigned int)dwrd);

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //more code
}
```

When I comment out the line

```
wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
```

RegisterClassEx(&wc) fails with error: ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Thank you

Comment: Call `ZeroMemory` first. There's very little performance penalty to it and then you can leave out all the `wc.* = 0;` statements.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Setting zero to hIcon, hIconSm and hCursor works fine. That means that the system goes to the default icons?

Comment: What `0` or `NULL` does to the various members is documented: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you comment out that line, the `wc.hIconSm` field does not get initialized and likely contains garbage values. `RegisterClassEx()` happens to notice this and complains.

Answer (score 1):

`RegisterClassEx(&wc)` will not work as you did not use `WNDCLASSEX`. Either use `WNDCLASS` and `RegisterClass` or `WNDCLASSEX` and `RegisterClassEx`.